# Sqlite syntax error near "?"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Simple enough; my code looks like this:

```
int idhash = getIdHash();
String[] args = {"runways", ""+idhash};
cursor = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE idhash = ?", args);
```

And I see this line in logcat:

```
E/SQLiteLog( 9570): (1) near "?": syntax error
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` only for binding literals. You cannot use it for binding identifiers such as table names. Identifiers must be in the SQL itself.

Comment: OK, that confirms my suspicion. Thanks.

Comment: I wound up switching to query() instead, it's cleaner that way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try

```
  Cursor cursor =  sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM runways WHERE idhash = ?", new String[]{idhash.toString()});
```

and it